# How Can I Pass An Event Handler Outside Of A Custom Class

Tags: vb.net, class, textbox, event-handling

I have created a custom Textbox using a new class of which inherits.  To this custom Textbox I have added two buttons (embedded) inside the control which are both declared inside the class.  One button is for Search and the other for Clear.

The purpose behind these buttons is to populate a Listview control when using Search and Clear the results when using clear...pretty straight forward.

However, my issue that I need help with is...

Because I have declared these buttons inside of my custom class, I cannot work out how to pass a 'Click' event outside of the class and back to the form.  For example, if I type into the Textbox and hit the search button, I somehow need to execute code on the click event (and same for clear).

I have read a little about not being able to pass event handlers outside of the class it was created, but I'm not really familiar with this.

Is there/and if so what is the best way to achieve my results?  Is it possible to handle a click event outside of the class to pass information to other controls?

Any help appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: if your control is a compound control, it sounds like you built a UserControl, but maybe it is straight inheritance.  You need to declare a new event(s) and raise it when the buttons are clicked.  Typically, such a control would work as one thing (more or less the purpose of building such a thing) then raise events new events related to new control

Comment: Just add two public events to your class.  Say SearchClick and ClearClick.  Use the RaiseEvent statement in the buttons' Click event handler to raise the event.  Now anybody can subscribe these events, like you'd do in the Form class that hosts that ListView.

Comment: I had got as far as adding a handler to each button to handle the click event but I can't work out where to go from there. Would it be at all possible to post a small example so I can visually see what you mean.  Thanks very much for your time guys!

Comment: Hi Guys, just letting you know that I read this post... [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms973905.aspx) and it gave me a good understanding of how it works.  Also helped me solve my problem.  Thanks again for the advice.  Not sure how to close this post without an answer though.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from Hans Passant for putting me on the right track, I was able to refer to this site [Raising Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms973905.aspx) and solve my issue.